# Javascript get text between last 2 forward slashes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Apologies if this has been asked before but I couldn't find an answer.

If I have a string as follows

```
 var myString = "/text/text/text/text/TEXT I REQUIRE/text.text";
```

How would I grab the TEXT I REQUIRE? It will always be between the last 2 forward slashes but the amount of slashes and other text could vary.

Many thanks,

Clint

Comment: You can split it to get an array and target the arr length -2 index: https://jsfiddle.net/vsgodvt2/

Comment: And this is probably more elegant: https://jsfiddle.net/7nnbgyoL/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var myString = "/I/am/a/beautiful/TEXT I REQUIRE/man.example";
myString=myString.split("/");
console.log(myString[myString.length-2]);
```

Answer (score 3):

first you split the string to array then select element number:

```
var myString = "/text/text/text/text/TEXT I REQUIRE/text.text";
var res = myString.split("/"); 
var result = res[res.length-2];
```

and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a2hezycp/) link is show result on a element.